# MySQL delete all rows with abandoned IDs

Tags: mysql

In my database I have three tables: one contains words (word_id, word), the other lists categories (cat_id, cat_name) and third one assigns categories to all words (word_id, cat_id) (one or more categories per word).

Is it possible to delete all rows in the categories-to-words-table with a word_id that does not currently exist in the words table?

Comment: Use foreign keys (InnoDB) and cascades to prevent this from happening in the future. In addition to the `NOT IN` solutions presented below, a common way to do this is with a `LEFT JOIN` and then check for a null (-> missing) value on the right relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using this:

```
DELETE FROM categories_to_words
WHERE word_id NOT IN (SELECT word_id FROM words);
```

There are more efficient ways to do it, but that'll work.

HOWEVER: you should *really* investigate using foreign keys, because if you use them, you won't have problems like the one you're solving now.

Comment: Worked fine! And thanks for the hint! I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is a translation of your sentence:

```
delete from categories2words
    where word_id not in (select word_id from words);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
Delete from categories2words
where word_id not in (select word_id from words);
```